# finding the class of .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

i have a string objects of books which i have got from a JSON objects. This Book object has three Key value pairs, Title,Author and URL. I use a for loop to read each object and just put the title of the object as a button on the html page. But when the button is clicked i want the URL of the book to be alerted. As i read the objects i make Books objects and push it into an array for later use. but i am not able to Use .Click() method the URL is not right. Please see the code for better understanding. :-)

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) //I know that there is only 65 Books..jsonString.books.lenght is not working.
{
    var title = jsonString.books[i].title;
    var classname = title.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var author = jsonString.books[i].author;
    var URL = jsonString.books[i].url;
    var htmlString = '<div class="' + classname + '"><input type="button" value="' + title + '"></div>';
    $(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(function () {
        loadBook(URL);
    });

    OneBook = new Book(author, title, URL);
    arr.push(OneBook);
}
```

attachpoint is a reference in the html file that i got from

```
var attachpoint=document.querySelector('.buttonAttachPoint');
```

So in the above code the URL that i get on clicking is always the last object in the jsonString. this is happening coz of the for loop. So is there a way i can get to class name of the Div that has onclick or the title of the button so that i can get the URL from the array of objects i created? Or is there an easier way. Also could any one point out why "jsonString.books.lenght" is not working? Thanks in advance.:-) all the help much appreciated. :-)

Comment: `jsonString.books.lenght` should be `jsonString.books.length`. I also added a closing `}` to your `for` loop which you hopefully omitted by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a closure using an immediately invoked function expression should do the trick. Just replace this:

```
$(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(function () {
    loadBook(URL);
});
```

with this:

```
(function(URL) {
    $(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(function () {
        loadBook(URL);
    });
})(URL);
```

`URL` inside the scope of that anonymous function will have the value passed to it, which will be the correct value for that iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Thanks a lot Anthony...Could you please guide me as to how i can learn all these techniques in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript, variables are scoped to their function, rather than any block.

The functions you are binding to `click` have a closure over `URL` in the context of the loop as a whole, not over `URL` in the context of the loop iteration.

This means that whenever any of the functions are invoked, `URL` will have the last value that the loop sets it to.

You need to freeze the value of `URL` for each loop.  One way to do this is to have a function elsewhere that takes `URL` as an argument, and returns a function that closes over it, thus:

```
function getBookLoader(url) {
  return function (){
    loadBook(url);
  };
}
```

You can then replace your `... .click` line with the following:

```
$(htmlString).appendTo(attachPoint).click(getBookLoader(URL))
```

To answer the question in the title, the `target` property of an event contains the object to which the event was dispatched, and the `currentTarget` property contains the object whose listeners are currently being evaluated.  `currentTarget`should be the `div` in question.

Comment: Thanks paul.  I did not have an idea about currentTarget.